# iOS AVCaptureVideoDataOutput cost too much memory

Tags: ios, memory, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am using `AVFoundation` framework to capture video with iPhone camera, my codes:

```
 self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
 ...
 self.output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
 [self.session addOutput:self.output];
```

Before `[session addOutput]`, everything goes well, memory is limited to 3M, but after `[session addOutput]`, memory usage increase 0.06M per second, after some minutes, the App will crash because of memory warning. `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` seems cost too much memory, and maybe have a memory leak issue.

So how can i to reduce the memory usage?

iOS version: 7.1.1

Comment: Do you have zombies enabled?

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you solve this problem? If yes, please share your solution.

Comment: Do `[self.session addOutput:self.output];` in the main queue.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm currently experiencing the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67370456/5281431

Comment: Had the same problem. Anybody found the reason?

Comment: As @Gajendra mentioned below, I messed around with the `AVCaptureSession` session preset. using `.high` still cost me too much memory. I tried using `.medium` and significantly reduced the memory consumption and CPU usage, but the video quality is greatly reduced as well. I ended up trying using. the `.hd1280x720` preset and it doesn't use that much RAM and CPU usage but still had a pretty good quality.

Answer (score 1):

```
AVCaptureSession *mSession; ;
```

use session preset heigh instead of session preset photo

```
mSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh; //yes

mSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto; //no
```