# `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` consumes three times more memory than `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, performance, avfoundation

## Issue

I'm using AVFoundation to implement a Camera that is able to record videos while running special AI processing.

Having an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` (for video recording) **and** a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` (for processing AI) running at the same time is not supported (see [Can use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4944083/5281431)), so I have decided to use a single `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` which is able to record videos to a file while running the AI processing in the same `captureOutput(...)` callback.

To my surprise, doing that drastically increases RAM usage from **58 MB** to **187 MB** (!!!), and CPU from **3-5%** to **7-12%** **while idle**. While actually recording, the RAM goes up even more (**260 MB**!).

I am wondering what I did wrong here, since I disabled all the AI processing and just compared the differences between `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.

My code:

### `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`

#### Setup

```swift
    if let movieOutput = self.movieOutput {
      captureSession.removeOutput(movieOutput)
    }
    movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput!)
```

#### Delegate

(well there is none, `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` handles all that internally)

#### Benchmark

When idle, so not recording at all:

- RAM: **56 MB**
- CPU: **3-5%**

When recording using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.startRecording`:

- RAM: **56 MB** (how???)
- CPU: **20-30%**

### `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`

#### Setup

```swift
    // Video
    if let videoOutput = self.videoOutput {
      captureSession.removeOutput(videoOutput)
      self.videoOutput = nil
    }
    videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoQueue)
    videoOutput!.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput!)

    // Audio
    if let audioOutput = self.audioOutput {
      captureSession.removeOutput(audioOutput)
      self.audioOutput = nil
    }
    audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    audioOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: audioQueue)
    captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput!)
```

#### Delegate

```swift
extension CameraView: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate,
                      AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

  public final func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput,
                                  didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                                  from _: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // empty
  }

  public final func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput,
                                  didDrop buffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                                  from _: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // empty
  }
}
```

> yes, they are literally empty methods. My RAM and CPU usage is still that high without doing any work here.

#### Benchmark

When idle, so not recording at all:

- RAM: **151-187 MB**
- CPU: **7-12%**

When recording using a custom `AVAssetWriter`:

- RAM: **260 MB**
- CPU: **64%**

Why is the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` so much more efficient than an empty `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`? Also, why does it's RAM not go up at all when recording, compared to how my `AVAssetWriter` implementation alone consumes **80 MB**?

Here's my custom `AVAssetWriter` implementation: [`RecordingSession.swift`](https://github.com/cuvent/react-native-vision-camera/blob/frame-processors/ios/RecordingSession.swift), and [here's where I call it](https://github.com/cuvent/react-native-vision-camera/blob/a48ca839e93e6199ad731f348e19427774c92821/ios/CameraView%2BRecordVideo.swift#L16-L86).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` resource usage is not happening in your process. Maybe it's happening in `mediaserverd`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman how can I check that? If it's a special process for that, I assume it's recycling that allocated RAM, no? Also, how would that explain the difference in CPU usage for my process?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23509159/8279130), I tried messing around with the `sessionPreset` in the `AVCaptureSession` object. The default is set to `.high`, so I tried changing it to `.medium`. While the RAM consumption and CPU usage are reduced quite significantly, the video quality is also greatly reduced as well. I ended up using the `.hd1280x720` preset. The RAM consumption and CPU usage are not as high as using the default preset, and the quality is still pretty good.

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer the question. I don't get how the video data output uses **more** memory than the movie output.